# I have a sql server stored procedure that quite fast in a server, but it is too slow in other one.

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have an sp running well on a server, but the same sp runs too slow in other DB, (different server). I know where is the problem, but I cannot find the reason why is it too slow there. In my server, I have around 2000 rows in the main table (client table), but in the other one, I have around 7000. I know this is not so much, but in this case, since this sp is searching a word in several fields it could be slower than a regular one. Can some of you give me some advice? I did try with an Index, non clustered.
Thanks in advance

```
            INSERT INTO @varTable
                select distinct C.id from client C
                    INNER JOIN place pl ON pl.plid = C.id
                    LEFT OUTER JOIN country ctr ON ctr.nr = pl.country
                    LEFT OUTER JOIN person per ON per.id = C.id
                    LEFT OUTER JOIN property pr ON pr.id = C.id
                        WHERE 
                        (           
                                (NOT PR.VALUE IS NULL AND PR.VALUE LIKE '%' + @varSearch  + '%')
                                OR (pl.pl_a_name LIKE '%' + @FIRST_WORD + '%')
                                OR (NOT pl.add1 IS NULL AND pl.add1 LIKE '%' + @varSearch + '%')
                                OR (NOT pl.add2 IS NULL AND pl.add2 LIKE '%' + @varSearch + '%')
                                OR (NOT pl.add3 IS NULL AND pl.add3 LIKE '%' + @varSearch + '%')
                                OR (NOT pl.pcod IS NULL AND pl.pcod LIKE '%' + @varSearch + '%')
                                OR (NOT pl.descr IS NULL AND pl.descr LIKE '%' + @varSearch + '%')
                                OR (NOT pl.phone IS NULL AND pl.phone LIKE '%' + @varSearch + '%')
                                OR (NOT per.ctname IS NULL AND per.ctname LIKE '%' + @varSearch + '%') 
                                OR (NOT per.phone IS NULL AND per.phone LIKE '%' + @varSearch + '%')                                            
                        )
                        AND
                        C.COMPANY = @cia
                        and (@DEPT IS NULL OR C.DEPT in (SELECT nstr FROM iter_charlist_to_table(@DEPT_LIMIT,DEFAULT)))
                        AND ( (@state = 1 AND STATUS != '0') OR (@state <> 1  and STATUS = 'C') )       



            ;WITH DistinctClient AS (
                SELECT DISTINCT C.id, listpos
                    from @varTable C
                    INNER JOIN place pl ON pl.plid = C.id 
                    LEFT OUTER JOIN country ctr ON ctr.nr = pl.country
                    LEFT OUTER JOIN person per ON per.id = C.id
                    LEFT OUTER JOIN property pr ON pr.id = C.id

                    INNER JOIN iter_charlist_to_table(@SEARCH_NAME, ' ') L ON
                        (           
                                (NOT PR.VALUE IS NULL AND PR.VALUE LIKE '%' + L.str  + '%')
                                OR (pl.pl_a_name LIKE '%' + L.str + '%')
                                OR (NOT pl.add1 IS NULL AND pl.add1 LIKE '%' + L.str + '%')
                                OR (NOT pl.add2 IS NULL AND pl.add2 LIKE '%' + L.str + '%')
                                OR (NOT pl.add3 IS NULL AND pl.add3 LIKE '%' + L.str + '%')
                                OR (NOT pl.pcod IS NULL AND pl.pcod LIKE '%' + L.str + '%')
                                OR (NOT pl.descr IS NULL AND pl.descr LIKE '%' + L.str + '%')
                                OR (NOT pl.phone IS NULL AND pl.phone LIKE '%' + L.str + '%')
                                OR (NOT per.ctname IS NULL AND per.ctname LIKE '%' + L.str + '%') 
                                OR (NOT per.phone IS NULL AND per.phone LIKE '%' + L.str + '%')                     
                                OR (NOT per.cellphone IS NULL AND per.cellphone LIKE '%' + L.str + '%')                     
                        )           
            ), 
            DistinctClientsMatchingAllWords AS (
                SELECT TOP 100 DistinctClient.OBJ_NO FROM DistinctClient
                GROUP BY 
                    DistinctClient.id
                HAVING SUM(listpos) = @wsum
            )

            INSERT INTO @tempResults SELECT * FROM DistinctClientsMatchingAllWords
            END
```

Comment: The problem is `LIKE 'something%'` **CAN** use index but `LIKE '%something%'` **CAN'T**

Comment: If you want to search for words, create a full text index and use a full text search.

Comment: Are the servers identical in configuration? Are the tables being hit all indexed identically?

Comment: the tables, stored procedure and DB are the same. I am not sure about The server. I think it could happen something there, but I don't know what, I don't know much about that...

Answer (score 0):

That 1st CTE you're using as the nested query for the 2nd CTE with the GROUP BY / HAVING isn't helping. Try a temp table instead of the 1st CTE, create a unique clustered index on (id, listpos) and then reference the temp table in the 2nd CTE.  In fact, looks like the 2nd CTE isn't needed. Also, does your table variable have a unique clustered?  Juan's comment on the LIKE is also very true.  That's hurting things for sure... likely more than anything else.  Here's a rough version based on what I said.

```
INSERT INTO @varTable
select distinct C.id
from client C
INNER JOIN place pl ON pl.plid = C.id
LEFT OUTER JOIN country ctr ON ctr.nr = pl.country
LEFT OUTER JOIN person per ON per.id = C.id
LEFT OUTER JOIN property pr ON pr.id = C.id
    WHERE 
    (           
            (NOT PR.VALUE IS NULL AND PR.VALUE LIKE '%' + @varSearch  + '%')
            OR (pl.pl_a_name LIKE '%' + @FIRST_WORD + '%')
            OR (NOT pl.add1 IS NULL AND pl.add1 LIKE '%' + @varSearch + '%')
            OR (NOT pl.add2 IS NULL AND pl.add2 LIKE '%' + @varSearch + '%')
            OR (NOT pl.add3 IS NULL AND pl.add3 LIKE '%' + @varSearch + '%')
            OR (NOT pl.pcod IS NULL AND pl.pcod LIKE '%' + @varSearch + '%')
            OR (NOT pl.descr IS NULL AND pl.descr LIKE '%' + @varSearch + '%')
            OR (NOT pl.phone IS NULL AND pl.phone LIKE '%' + @varSearch + '%')
            OR (NOT per.ctname IS NULL AND per.ctname LIKE '%' + @varSearch + '%') 
            OR (NOT per.phone IS NULL AND per.phone LIKE '%' + @varSearch + '%')                                            
    )
    AND
    C.COMPANY = @cia
    and (@DEPT IS NULL OR C.DEPT in (SELECT nstr FROM iter_charlist_to_table(@DEPT_LIMIT,DEFAULT)))
    AND ( (@state = 1 AND STATUS != '0') OR (@state <> 1  and STATUS = 'C') )       

SELECT DISTINCT C.id, listpos
INTO #DistinctClient
from @varTable C
INNER JOIN place pl ON pl.plid = C.id 
LEFT OUTER JOIN country ctr ON ctr.nr = pl.country
LEFT OUTER JOIN person per ON per.id = C.id
LEFT OUTER JOIN property pr ON pr.id = C.id
INNER JOIN iter_charlist_to_table(@SEARCH_NAME, ' ') L ON
    (           
            (NOT PR.VALUE IS NULL AND PR.VALUE LIKE '%' + L.str  + '%')
            OR (pl.pl_a_name LIKE '%' + L.str + '%')
            OR (NOT pl.add1 IS NULL AND pl.add1 LIKE '%' + L.str + '%')
            OR (NOT pl.add2 IS NULL AND pl.add2 LIKE '%' + L.str + '%')
            OR (NOT pl.add3 IS NULL AND pl.add3 LIKE '%' + L.str + '%')
            OR (NOT pl.pcod IS NULL AND pl.pcod LIKE '%' + L.str + '%')
            OR (NOT pl.descr IS NULL AND pl.descr LIKE '%' + L.str + '%')
            OR (NOT pl.phone IS NULL AND pl.phone LIKE '%' + L.str + '%')
            OR (NOT per.ctname IS NULL AND per.ctname LIKE '%' + L.str + '%') 
            OR (NOT per.phone IS NULL AND per.phone LIKE '%' + L.str + '%')                     
            OR (NOT per.cellphone IS NULL AND per.cellphone LIKE '%' + L.str + '%')                     
    )

CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX ix_DistinctClientClustered ON #DistinctClient (id, listpos)

INSERT INTO @tempResults
SELECT TOP 100 OBJ_NO
FROM #DistinctClient
GROUP BY id
HAVING SUM(listpos) = @wsum

END
```

Comment: The problem is the `LIKE '% ... %` predicate. This *has* to check all rows. Replacing the table variable with a temporary table won't help

Comment: I replaced the CTE, not the table variable. Yes, the LIKE is the biggest problem... totally agree.  I said that in my post.  My query was to help the aggregate portion and remove the multiple nested CTEs.

Comment: I know a temp table shouldn't help, but the strange thing is that actually with a temp table the response time is now 10 seconds lower.

Comment: I just did the test on other customer server, with more data and it works perfectly. So this is really strange.